Pandas crashing (segmentation fault) in Python 3.10.n during import
When I try to import Pandas in Python 3.10.14 in MacOS zsh, python3 crashes with segmentation fault.
sudiptabhawmik@Sudiptas-iPro gippss % python3
Python 3.10.14 (main, May  6 2024, 14:47:20) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
zsh: segmentation fault  python3


I tried Pandas from version 2.2.2 down to 2.0.3
How can I resolve this?
I tried changing zsh to bash and csh, didn't work.
I tried multiple versions of Pandas from 2.2.2 to 2.0.3 but failed.

Does this happen for any other packages?

No. Haven't encountered any as yet.

Are you using the Python provided with macOS or a Conda one?

Installed using conda.

What happens when you launch your conda/python/pandas from bash instead of zsh?

I was able to resolve the issue by installing both python and Pandas with Conda. Mixing Conda Python and Pip Pandas caused the issue.
However, this may be an issue with MacOS versions and might not cause issues in Linux.
